# Django "TemplateDoesNotExist " Error but "Using loader django.template.loaders.app_directories.Loader" File Exists

Tags: python, django, django-templates

**Template Loader finds the template but template is not loaded**

```
TemplateDoesNotExist at /cardpayment/

cardpayment.html

Request Method:     GET
Request URL:    http://localhost:7000/cardpayment/
Django Version:     1.8
Exception Type:     TemplateDoesNotExist
Exception Value:    

cardpayment.html

Exception Location:     /home/sdr/sl/lib/python3.4/site-packages/django/template/loader.py in render_to_string, line 138
Python Executable:  /home/sdr/sl/bin/python
Python Version:     3.4.3
Python Path:    

['/home/sdr/sl/agryp',
 '/home/sdr/pycharm-4.0.6/helpers/pydev',
 '/home/sdr/sl/src/tastypie',
 '/home/sdr/sl/agryp',
 '/usr/local/lib/python34.zip',
 '/usr/local/lib/python3.4',
 '/usr/local/lib/python3.4/plat-linux',
 '/usr/local/lib/python3.4/lib-dynload',
 '/home/sdr/sl/lib/python3.4/site-packages']

Server time:    Tue, 5 May 2015 10:17:40 +0000
Template-loader postmortem

Django tried loading these templates, in this order:

    Using loader django.template.loaders.filesystem.Loader:
        /home/sdr/sl/agryp/templates/cardpayment.html (File does not exist)
    Using loader django.template.loaders.app_directories.Loader:
        /home/sdr/sl/agryp/agryp/templates/cardpayment.html (File exists) <=========== FILE EXISTS BUT NOT LOADED
        /home/sdr/sl/src/tastypie/tastypie/templates/cardpayment.html (File does not exist)
        /home/sdr/sl/lib/python3.4/site-packages/grappelli/templates/cardpayment.html (File does not exist)
        /home/sdr/sl/lib/python3.4/site-packages/django/contrib/admin/templates/cardpayment.html (File does not exist)
        /home/sdr/sl/lib/python3.4/site-packages/django/contrib/auth/templates/cardpayment.html (File does not exist)
        /home/sdr/sl/lib/python3.4/site-packages/oauth2_provider/templates/cardpayment.html (File does not exist)
        /home/sdr/sl/lib/python3.4/site-packages/selectable/templates/cardpayment.html (File does not exist)
```

As it can be clearly seen, the loader is able to find the template.

The TEMPLATE_DIRS value in settings.py is as follows:

```
TEMPLATES = [
    {
        'BACKEND': 'django.template.backends.django.DjangoTemplates',
        'DIRS': [ os.path.join(BASE_DIR, "templates"),],
        'APP_DIRS': True,
        'OPTIONS': {
            'context_processors': [
                'django.template.context_processors.debug',
                'django.template.context_processors.request',
                'django.contrib.auth.context_processors.auth',
                'django.contrib.messages.context_processors.messages',
                'allauth.account.context_processors.account',
                'allauth.socialaccount.context_processors.socialaccount',
            ],
        },
    },
]
```

I have tried to move the template to project/templates directory as well but the error persists.

Code checks out with 0 errors/warnings.

**contents of cardpayment.html**

```
{% extends "base.html" %}
{% block title %}Card Payments over Phone{% endblock %}
{% block extrahead %}
    {% load selectable_tags %}
    {% include_ui_theme %}
{% endblock %}

{% block content %}
    <h1>Receive Card Payment</h1>
    <form name="paymentType"  id="paymentType" class="form-horizontal">
    <fieldset>
        <label>Check type of Customer
        <input type="radio" value="existing">Existing Customer<br />
        <input type="radio"  value="new">Nee Customer<br />
        </label>
    </fieldset>
    </form>

    <div class="row">
    <form class="form-horizontal">
        <table class="table-responsive table-bordered">
            {{ form.as_table }}
        </table>
    </form>
    </div>
{% endblock %}
```

Comment: What the filepath of cardpayment.html?

Comment: /home/sdr/sl/agryp/agryp/templates/cardpayment.html (File exists)
BASE_DIR is ~/sl/agryp, agryp is the app directory.

Comment: Please check permissions for this file, it can be that while the file exists, Django can't get read access for it

Comment: First thing I checked. File ownership is user 'sdr', django is running under the same user (runserver) and I did a chmod a+r on the file just to be sure and of course it being under the app directory django has all permissions.

Actually the django template loader ** does** find the template, but does not load it.

Comment: Post content of cardpayment.html

Comment: @b-rat is base.html exists?

Comment: base.html exists. I am able to load other templates without any errors.

Comment: I commented out the include directives and tried, to no avail, The error persists.

Answer (score 9):

i've been running into the same problem, the solution that work was to specify my template directory (projects/templates) in templates settings like this:

```
TEMPLATES = [
{
    'BACKEND': 'django.template.backends.django.DjangoTemplates',
    'DIRS': ['templates'],
    'APP_DIRS': True,
    'OPTIONS': {
        'context_processors': [
            'django.template.context_processors.debug',
            'django.template.context_processors.request',
            'django.contrib.auth.context_processors.auth',
            'django.contrib.messages.context_processors.messages',
            "django.core.context_processors.media",
        ],
    },
},
```

]

Answer (score 5):

**`TemplateDoesNotExist... cardpayment.html`** might mean Django can't find `cardpayment.html`, ***or*** it might mean it **can** find cardpayment.html no problem, but can't find some  `{% include 'cardpayment_subsection.html' %}` within it.

*Explanation:*

I got this error just now, in a project that's been working for years, and the other solutions here didn't help me.

**My `cardpayment.html` *was* being found by the template loaders, but contained some nonsense** which meant it could not be rendered.
The error messages mislead me into thinking Django didn't know the file exists, when in fact it knew it existed, just couldn't successfully render it.

For a while everything was working fine: `cardpayment.html` was being rendered without a problem.

views.py

```
def cardpaymentview(request):            
    return render_to_response("cardpayment.html", {
            "message": "Hi SO"
            }, context_instance=RequestContext(request))
```

Suddenly, even though I hadn't been editing `cardpayment.html`, I got that error:

**TemplateDoesNotExist at /cardpaymentpage:
cardpayment.html**

```
Using loader django.template.loaders.app_directories.Loader:
folder/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/contrib/admin/templates/cardpayment.html (File does not exist)
folder/project/app1/templates/cardpayment.html (File does not exist)
folder/project/app2/templates/cardpayment.html (File does not exist)
folder/project/paymentapp/templates/cardpayment.html (File exists)
```

**The problem was** that my `cardpayment.html` in turn has an `include` calling another template:

```
{% include 'cardpayment_subsection.html' %}
```

**I created the error by** renaming the file `cardpayment_subsection.html` to `something_else.html`, without editing `cardpayment.html`, so that `include` command naturally failed.

But as you can see, the debug message didn't indicate the problem was callling the `cardpayment_subsection.html` (file no longer exists).

Summary: if other solutions don't work for you, try creating a test file `cardpayment2.html` that simply says "Hello world" and see if you can at least render that instead. Maybe the `cardpayment.html` file is being read, but has an error within it. (In my case, I needed to change the `{% include '____.html' %}` to refer to a file that actually does exist!)

Answer (score 3):

I'm also using the `DIRS` config option in a similar way to you and I've just run into the same problem in Django 1.8.2. The issue seems to relate to the way you invoke `django.shortcuts.render` (or `django.shortcuts.render_to_response`) in your views - are you using these?

TL;DR - try changing your invocation of `render_to_response` in your views so that you don't pass a `context_instance` **or any deprecated argument**, such as the previously often used `django.template.RequestContext`. If you do pass a `context_instance`, or any deprecated argument, the django template loading code uses a legacy path that doesn't support the `DIRS` option and your template will not be loaded - even if it exists on disk.

Here's a section of relevant code from the Django source (`django/shortcuts.py`) that shows how this situation comes about:

```
def render_to_response(template_name, context=None,
                       context_instance=_context_instance_undefined,
                       content_type=None, status=None, dirs=_dirs_undefined,
                       dictionary=_dictionary_undefined, using=None):
    """
    Returns a HttpResponse whose content is filled with the result of calling
    django.template.loader.render_to_string() with the passed arguments.
    """
    if (context_instance is _context_instance_undefined
            and dirs is _dirs_undefined
            and dictionary is _dictionary_undefined):
        # No deprecated arguments were passed - use the new code path
        content = loader.render_to_string(template_name, context, using=using)

    else:
        # Some deprecated arguments were passed - use the legacy code path
        content = loader.render_to_string(
            template_name, context, context_instance, dirs, dictionary,
            using=using)

    return HttpResponse(content, content_type, status)
```

If you follow this through to the loader's `render_to_string` method (in `django/template/loader.py`) you can see your template won't be loaded if you pass any deprecated arguments to `render_to_reponse` in your views:

```
def render_to_string(template_name, context=None,
                     context_instance=_context_instance_undefined,
                     dirs=_dirs_undefined,
                     dictionary=_dictionary_undefined,
                     request=None, using=None):
    """
    Loads a template and renders it with a context. Returns a string.

    template_name may be a string or a list of strings.
    """
    if (context_instance is _context_instance_undefined
            and dirs is _dirs_undefined
            and dictionary is _dictionary_undefined):
        # No deprecated arguments were passed - use the new code path
        if isinstance(template_name, (list, tuple)):
            template = select_template(template_name, using=using)
        else:
            template = get_template(template_name, using=using)
        return template.render(context, request)

    else:
        # Some deprecated arguments were passed - use the legacy code path
        for engine in _engine_list(using):
            try:
                # This is required for deprecating properly arguments specific
                # to Django templates. Remove Engine.render_to_string() at the
                # same time as this code path in Django 2.0.
                if isinstance(engine, DjangoTemplates):
                    if request is not None:
                        raise ValueError(
                            "render_to_string doesn't support the request argument "
                            "when some deprecated arguments are passed.")
                        continue
                    # Hack -- use the internal Engine instance of DjangoTemplates.
                    return engine.engine.render_to_string(
                        template_name, context, context_instance, dirs, dictionary)
                elif context_instance is not _context_instance_undefined:
                    warnings.warn(
                        "Skipping template backend %s because its render_to_string "
                        "method doesn't support the context_instance argument." %
                        engine.name, stacklevel=2)
                elif dirs is not _dirs_undefined:
                    warnings.warn(
                        "Skipping template backend %s because its render_to_string "
                        "method doesn't support the dirs argument." % engine.name,
                        stacklevel=2)
                elif dictionary is not _dictionary_undefined:
                    warnings.warn(
                        "Skipping template backend %s because its render_to_string "
                        "method doesn't support the dictionary argument." %
                        engine.name, stacklevel=2)
            except TemplateDoesNotExist:
                continue

        if template_name:
            if isinstance(template_name, (list, tuple)):
                template_name = ', '.join(template_name)
            raise TemplateDoesNotExist(template_name)
        else:
            raise TemplateDoesNotExist("No template names provided")
```

Answer (score 2):

Found a fix. I am not sure why but the new TEMPLATES directive (Django 1.8+) does not seem to be working. I commented that out and put in the old style

```
TEMPLATE_DIRS = (
    '/home/sdr/sl/agryp/templates/',
 )
```

directive, everything started working again. ARGH!

Will need to work out why the new TEMPLATES directive is causing me problems.

Thanks for trying to help guys!

Comment: I resolved this by adding path to my templates to TEMPLATES['DIRS']

Comment: @MartinM your suggestion solved! thank you very much. you could add your suggestion as an answer to the question

Answer (score 0):

Find settings.py in your python project and add following line. I hope it will work

```
SETTINGS_PATH = os.path.normpath(os.path.dirname(__file__))
TEMPLATE_DIRS = (
   os.path.join(SETTINGS_PATH, 'templates'),
)
```

Answer (score 0):

Django’s template system was overhauled in Django 1.8 when it gained support for multiple template engines.

**The TEMPLATES settings**

A new setting was introduced in Django 1.8: `TEMPLATES`. All existing template-related settings were deprecated.

During the deprecation period, Django will create a backwards-compatible `TEMPLATES` based on the `TEMPLATE_*` settings if you don’t define it yourself.

Here’s how to define `TEMPLATES` in your settings module.

If you’re using the default value of `TEMPLATE_LOADERS`, that is, if it isn’t defined in your settings file or if it’s set to:

```
['django.template.loaders.filesystem.Loader',
 'django.template.loaders.app_directories.Loader']
```

then you should define TEMPLATES as follows:

```
TEMPLATES = [
    {
        'BACKEND': 'django.template.backends.django.DjangoTemplates',
        'DIRS': [
            # insert your TEMPLATE_DIRS here
        ],
        'APP_DIRS': True,
        'OPTIONS': {
            'context_processors': [
                # Insert your TEMPLATE_CONTEXT_PROCESSORS here or use this
                # list if you haven't customized them:
                'django.contrib.auth.context_processors.auth',
                'django.template.context_processors.debug',
                'django.template.context_processors.i18n',
                'django.template.context_processors.media',
                'django.template.context_processors.static',
                'django.template.context_processors.tz',
                'django.contrib.messages.context_processors.messages',
            ],
        },
    },
]
```

More information can be found here https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/ref/templates/upgrading/

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem and it was solved after changing the order of the apps in `INSTALLED_APPS` in the *settings.py* file.
You can also solve this by adding
'rest_framework', into the list of INSTALLED APPS inside settings.py
Put your app's name first on the list:

```
INSTALLED_APPS = [
    'module_name',
    'django.contrib.admin',
    'django.contrib.auth',
    'django.contrib.contenttypes',
    'django.contrib.sessions',
    'django.contrib.messages',
    'django.contrib.staticfiles',
]
```

Answer (score 0):

Check the directory where your templates are store and add
in settings.py

```
Templates
 'DIRS': [r'C:_________________________________'],
```

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).