# Django 1.8 TEMPLATE-DEBUG = True setting sets off Template Not Found Error

Tags: django, debugging, templates

DJANGO 1.8 Python 3.4

I had previously encountered the TEMPLATES array setting generating error "Template not found" when the Django template loader in fact reports that it found the template. This I was able to work around by reverting to the TEMPLATE_DIRS setting.[See the Question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30050634/django-templatedoesnotexist-error-but-using-loader-django-template-loaders-a)

I needed to debug a template, so i set TEMPLATE_DEBUG to True... and it again generated the Template not found error:

index.html

Request Method:     GET
Request URL:    http://127.0.0.1:7000/
Django Version:     1.8.2
Exception Type:     TemplateDoesNotExist
Exception Value:

```
index.html

Exception Location:     /home/sdr/sl/lib/python3.4/site-packages/django/template/loader.py in render_to_string, line 138
Python Executable:  /home/sdr/sl/bin/python
Python Version:     3.4.3
Python Path:    

['/home/sdr/sl/agryp',
 '/home/sdr/pycharm-4.5/helpers/pydev',
 '/home/sdr/sl/src/tastypie',
 '/home/sdr/sl/agryp',
 '/usr/local/lib/python34.zip',
 '/usr/local/lib/python3.4',
 '/usr/local/lib/python3.4/plat-linux',
 '/usr/local/lib/python3.4/lib-dynload',
 '/home/sdr/sl/lib/python3.4/site-packages']

Server time:    Thu, 28 May 2015 04:05:11 +0000
Template-loader postmortem

Django tried loading these templates, in this order:

    Using loader django.template.loaders.filesystem.Loader:
        /home/sdr/sl/agryp/templates/index.html (File exists)
```

Error persists whether I use TEMPLATES=[] setting or TEMPLATE_DIRS setting.

I would appreciate some insight in to the problem.

Answer (score 1):

Make sure you have provided templates folder path in settings.py Or check your template path is correct in views.py

In Django 1.8 it will be like this

```
TEMPLATES = [
    {
        'BACKEND': 'django.template.backends.django.DjangoTemplates',
        'DIRS': [os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'templates')],
        'APP_DIRS': True,
        'OPTIONS': {
            'context_processors': [
                'django.template.context_processors.debug',
                'django.template.context_processors.request',
                'django.contrib.auth.context_processors.auth',
                'django.contrib.messages.context_processors.messages',
            ],
        },
    },
]
```

This worked for me.

Comment: Thank you for your response.

Yes Indeed, the path and TEMPLATES setting is correct - as the loader shows file as found. 

the It even works for me with a fresh project. After I add code to my project the TEMPLATES= settings. I have for the moment decided to go forward with coding. It's some vague interaction between the apps I have added (like tastypie etc.) and will no doubt take time to track down.