# Django view not loading from the project folder

Tags: python, django

I'm having an issue with loading a view in Django. FYI very new to Django ;)

The error that I'm getting is **TemplateDoesNotExist at /polls/**

Django is loading from the "Exception Location
"/Users/NAME/anaconda/envs/Django/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/template/loader.py"

It should load from "/Users/NAME/Documents/Django/template/index.html"

I have in my APP view.py

```
return render(request,'index.html')
```

My settings.py

```
TEMPLATES = [
    {
        'BACKEND': 'django.template.backends.django.DjangoTemplates',
        'DIRS': ["/Users/NAME/Documents/Django/template/"],
```

How do I load from the view from my project file?

file structure

```
total 0

drwxr-xr-x  6 NAME  staff  204 11 Aug 16:17 Django

drwxr-xr-x  6 NAME  staff  204 26 Jun 23:17 test




./Django:

total 32

drwxr-xr-x  10 NAME  staff    340 11 Aug 16:17 Django

-rw-r--r--   1 NAME  staff  12288 10 Aug 21:09 db.sqlite3

-rwxr-xr-x   1 NAME  staff    804 10 Aug 21:08 manage.py

drwxr-xr-x  15 NAME  staff    510 11 Aug 16:17 polls



./Django/Django:

total 56

-rw-r--r--  1 NAME  staff     0 10 Aug 21:08 __init__.py

-rw-r--r--  1 NAME  staff   147 10 Aug 21:09 __init__.pyc

-rw-r--r--  1 NAME  staff  3160 11 Aug 10:14 settings.py

-rw-r--r--  1 NAME  staff  2648 11 Aug 10:14 settings.pyc

-rw-r--r--  1 NAME  staff   176 10 Aug 21:24 urls.py

-rw-r--r--  1 NAME  staff   402 10 Aug 21:25 urls.pyc

-rw-r--r--  1 NAME  staff   390 10 Aug 21:08 wsgi.py

-rw-r--r--  1 NAME  staff   603 10 Aug 21:09 wsgi.pyc



./Django/polls:

total 80

-rw-r--r--  1 NAME  staff    0 10 Aug 21:19 __init__.py

-rw-r--r--  1 NAME  staff  146 10 Aug 21:25 __init__.pyc

-rw-r--r--  1 NAME  staff  128 10 Aug 21:19 admin.py

-rw-r--r--  1 NAME  staff  150 10 Aug 21:19 apps.py

drwxr-xr-x  3 NAME  staff  102 10 Aug 21:19 migrations

-rw-r--r--  1 NAME  staff  122 10 Aug 21:19 models.py

-rw-r--r--  1 NAME  staff  264 10 Aug 21:43 models.pyc

drwxr-xr-x  3 NAME  staff  102 10 Aug 21:40 templates

-rw-r--r--  1 NAME  staff  125 10 Aug 21:19 tests.py

-rw-r--r--  1 NAME  staff  116 10 Aug 21:23 urls.py

-rw-r--r--  1 NAME  staff  326 10 Aug 21:25 urls.pyc

-rw-r--r--  1 NAME  staff  184 11 Aug 15:56 views.py

-rw-r--r--  1 NAME  staff  483 11 Aug 15:56 views.pyc
```

Comment: The error page usually shows the folders Django has tried to load the template from.

Comment: Please show the layout of your `Django/polls/templates` directory and subdirectories.

Comment: Hey guys, sorry for the late reply. I left my computer at the office over the weekend. 

Klaus D. see below

Using engine django:
`django.template.loaders.app_directories.Loader: /Users/NAME/anaconda/envs/Django/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/contrib/admin/templates/index.html (Source does not exist)`
`django.template.loaders.app_directories.Loader: /Users/NAME/anaconda/envs/Django/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/contrib/auth/templates/index.html (Source does not exist)
`
Alasdair
/Users/name/Documents/Django/Django/polls/templates 

it just has the index.html file in it

Answer (score 0):

Django is still searching the old directory /polls/ for the template, there could be a few reasons for this. The simplist solution is to make sure you stop your server, and restart it again. In the django development server, when you save a file it will do a soft reload, however, any changes to the settings.py file require a full stop (using Ctrl+C) and restart to be implemented.

Also, to make sure that the directory is correct, I would recommend adding

```
import os
```

at the start of your file and

```
print{os.getcwd()}
```

Right before your return. That way you can see the full path that it is searching in.

Comment: Tried restarting the server and added the below code

 return HttpResponse(os.getcwd())

This was the out put

/Users/NAME/Documents/Django/Django

Comment: How is your file tree setup? The path you provided leads me to believe that the current directory is not the same directory where your templates folder is, possibly causing an issue. An easy fix would be to move your templates folder into the second django folder and then update the template DIR in your settings file.

Comment: Just added the folder file structure to the main post

Answer (score 0):

Specifying directories like below:

```
'DIRS': ["/Users/NAME/Documents/Django/template/"],
```

is wrong. You should use `path.join` with BASE_DIR to construct paths. Also I don't think you need to specify template directory at all if you leave it empty then also it will work.

```
'DIRS': []
```

When you leave it empty Django will search template in `app_folder/templates`

Issue with your settings is first your path is wrong, Your template resides in polls directory not Django directory. Second you also have a typo `template` whereas it should be `templates`.

Solution: specify this -

```
'DIRS': []
```

in your settings and others settings and codes are fine.

Answer (score 0):

I worked it out,

in the **setting.py** file it was

```
'DIRS': ["/Users/NAME/Documents/Django/template/"],
```

needs to be

```
'DIRS': ['polls/templates'],
```

It seams the Django community is quite strong and helpful. This will be the main reason I'll keep using Django :)

Big thanks to everyone for helping me out. sorry for the nube question.

Comment: Also the it was from this post https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30050634/django-templatedoesnotexist-error-but-using-loader-django-template-loaders-a