# TemplateDoesNotFound Error after deploying django app in heroku

Tags: django, heroku

I have deployed my Django app successfully on Heroku. But it is not running at all. The problem showing here is TemplateDoesNotExist error which tells it could not find the *base.html* file which I extended at every other template. But I have all the templates up and running on the local environment.

Here is a log of the errors-

```
TemplateDoesNotExist at /
base.html 
Request Method: GET
Request URL:    https://barikoi.herokuapp.com/
Django Version: 2.2
Exception Type: TemplateDoesNotExist
Exception Value:    
base.html 
Exception Location: /app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/template/backends/django.py in reraise, line 84
Python Executable:  /app/.heroku/python/bin/python
Python Version: 3.6.11
Python Path:    
['/app/.heroku/python/bin',
 '/app',
 '/app/.heroku/python/lib/python36.zip',
 '/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.6',
 '/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.6/lib-dynload',
 '/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.6/site-packages']
Server time:    Sun, 12 Jul 2020 13:26:22 +0000
```

Template loader postmortem shows the following issues-

```
Template-loader postmortem
Django tried loading these templates, in this order:

Using engine django:

django.template.loaders.filesystem.Loader: /app/templates/base.html (Source does not exist)
django.template.loaders.app_directories.Loader: /app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/contrib/admin/templates/base.html (Source does not exist)
django.template.loaders.app_directories.Loader: /app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/contrib/auth/templates/base.html (Source does not exist)
```

The *settings.py* file looks like the following-

```
import django_heroku
import os

# Build paths inside the project like this: os.path.join(BASE_DIR, ...)
BASE_DIR = os.path.dirname(os.path.dirname(os.path.abspath(__file__)))


# Quick-start development settings - unsuitable for production
# See https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/howto/deployment/checklist/

# SECURITY WARNING: keep the secret key used in production secret!
SECRET_KEY =

# SECURITY WARNING: don't run with debug turned on in production!
DEBUG = True

ALLOWED_HOSTS = []


# Application definition

INSTALLED_APPS = [
    'pages.apps.PagesConfig',
    'listings.apps.ListingsConfig',
    'realtors.apps.RealtorsConfig',
    'django.contrib.admin',
    'django.contrib.auth',
    'django.contrib.contenttypes',
    'django.contrib.sessions',
    'django.contrib.messages',
    'django.contrib.staticfiles',
    'django.contrib.humanize',
    'django.contrib.sites',
]

SITE_ID = 1

MIDDLEWARE = [
    'django.middleware.security.SecurityMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.sessions.middleware.SessionMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.common.CommonMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.csrf.CsrfViewMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.auth.middleware.AuthenticationMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.messages.middleware.MessageMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.clickjacking.XFrameOptionsMiddleware',
]

ROOT_URLCONF = 'btre.urls'

TEMPLATES = [
    {
        'BACKEND': 'django.template.backends.django.DjangoTemplates',
        'DIRS': [os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'templates')],
        'APP_DIRS': True,
        'OPTIONS': {
            'context_processors': [
                'django.template.context_processors.debug',
                'django.template.context_processors.request',
                'django.contrib.auth.context_processors.auth',
                'django.contrib.messages.context_processors.messages',
            ],
        },
    },
]

WSGI_APPLICATION = 'btre.wsgi.application'


# Database
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/ref/settings/#databases

DATABASES = {
    'default': {
        'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.postgresql',
        'NAME': 'parvez',
        'USER': ,
        'PASSWORD':,
        'HOST': 'localhost'
    }
}


# Password validation
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/ref/settings/#auth-password-validators

AUTH_PASSWORD_VALIDATORS = [
    {
        'NAME': 'django.contrib.auth.password_validation.UserAttributeSimilarityValidator',
    },
    {
        'NAME': 'django.contrib.auth.password_validation.MinimumLengthValidator',
    },
    {
        'NAME': 'django.contrib.auth.password_validation.CommonPasswordValidator',
    },
    {
        'NAME': 'django.contrib.auth.password_validation.NumericPasswordValidator',
    },
]


# Internationalization
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/topics/i18n/

LANGUAGE_CODE = 'en-us'

TIME_ZONE = 'UTC'

USE_I18N = True

USE_L10N = True

USE_TZ = True


# Static files (CSS, JavaScript, Images)
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/howto/static-files/

STATIC_ROOT = os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'static')
STATIC_URL = '/static/'
STATICFILES_DIRS = [
    os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'btre/static')
]

# Media Folder Settings
MEDIA_ROOT = os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'media')
MEDIA_URL = '/media/'

# Activate Django-Heroku.
django_heroku.settings(locals())
```

I tried the solution from this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30050634/django-templatedoesnotexist-error-but-using-loader-django-template-loaders-a) but it did not work in my case.

I checked everything on the local environment, everything seemed ok.

My development environment is windows.

Comment: @ hasan parvez  could you add your ```settings``` as well

Comment: @iliya Ok, I have added that

Comment: @ hasan parvez login to your server by terminal and check the directories to find out that you uploaded templates as well then report back.